# Get the title instead of the number of a referenced chapter/section?

Tags: cross-referencing

In my document I am referencing a section, e.g.

```
\section{My Section}\label{test}
Also see section\ref{test}
```

This gives me, e.g.

> Also see section 1

but what I want is:

> Also see section My Section

How can I do that?

[Edit: comment moved to question body]

Of course it makes more sense to have something like "chapter 1 My Section", therefore mentioning chapter number and title. Anyways, this is just an example and you can easily combine both.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) package does what you want (and cooperates well with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}% Only if hyperref isn't loaded
% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}\label{test}

Some text.

\section{bar}

Some text. Also see section \nameref{test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is worth noting that for this to work, it is not necessary for section numbering to be enabled. I.e. one can use `\section*`.

Comment: An alternative is package `titleref`.