# \ref Chapter Name in LaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the title instead of number of a referenced chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/get-the-title-instead-of-number-of-a-referenced-chapter)

Is it possible to use `\ref{chap:conclusion}`  to refer to the actual name of the chapter instead of the chapter counter in LaTeX? So that I can do this:

`See the \ref{chap:conclusion} chapter for more information`

`See the Conclusion chapter for more information`

instead of:

`See Chapter \ref{chap:conclusion} for more`

`See Chapter 6 for more`

Comment: The `memoir` package, among other, implements this. More information here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=nameref

Comment: I think we've done this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491842/references-with-text-in-latex. In addition  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943907/latex-links and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522838/how-do-i-emit-the-text-content-of-a-reference-in-latex are closely related.

Comment: BTW-- I think that this versions has a more searchable title and should not be deleted.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You could use the `nameref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{Me, myself and I} 
\label{intro}
Hi, my name is Bart.

\section{Summary}
I introduced myself in section: \nameref{intro}.

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: example image]