# How to reference chapter/section title when using cleveref

Tags: cleveref

As the title says, how can you reference a chapter or section title when using cref?
To be more clear: I do not want the label "section" or "chapter", I want the actual title of the chapter or section..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[norsk,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\section{Title}


\section{another title}
%I want to reference the first section here, with its name


\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `\label` so you have something to refer to. Then use `\cref{label name}` and `\nameref{label name}` for the title.

Comment: so cleveref dont have a command similar to nameref? I would want the name clickable..

Comment: @miniHessel related: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66896/ref-chapter-name-in-latex), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/get-the-title-instead-of-the-number-of-a-referenced-chapter-section), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491842/references-with-text-in-latex)

Comment: @egwenesedai no, not at all. I am talking about cleveref.

Comment: @miniHessel, did you test it. The name *is* clickable.

Comment: @daleif ye if you use normal nameref it is. Thanks

Comment: @miniHessel, and your point is? Not exactly clear what you are actually asking? As Yo's solution below shows the references *are* clickable

Comment: as I commented to @yo's : I thought the best approach would be to use either cleveref or hyperref. Guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 15):

This:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[norsk,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\section{Title}


\section{another title}
\label{sss}
%I want to reference the first section here, with its name

nameref: \nameref{sss}\\
cref: \cref{sss}\\
ref: \ref{sss}

\end{document}
```

Gives this after 2 or 3 compilations:

[image]

Comment: Where does the `avsnitt` come from?

Comment: @Trylks From the Norsk language?

Comment: I see, so it means "section" I guess. I was asking because I have a [related problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238579/cref-reference-format-for-label-type-undefined-for-section) but it seems to be different. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

So, if I understand the comments and suggestions correctly:

Cleveref actually don't have a function equal to nameref, so the solution is to use normal \nameref

Comment: Yes, exactly. Why in the world would it double something that is (1) painful to implement and (2) perfectly done by `hyperref`?!

Comment: I just thought the best "approach" would be to use one of them through the whole document. Guess I got blinded by that.

Comment: Just FYI, `cleveref` _does_ have `namecref` and many variants, but those similarly-named operations don't do what you want: the actual **name** of the labeled element. As you noticed, they instead give you the name of the "class" of element (e.g. section, chapter).