# How can I reference a section but exclude the section number?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, labels

I have numbered sections (and I want to keep them numbered, eg. `1. Introduction`), but I would like to be able to reference a section without the number appearing (eg. `Introduction`). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I think it is the same case as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66898/289051)

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I have been lurking here for a long time but have never had the rep to do much. Thought I finally found a question that was worth asking. Daniel Delimata, thanks for the link, had looked for a similar case but was unsuccessful.