# Referencing name of file in separate file, none of which is the main file

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a main file (say, `main.tex`) and two chapters in separate files (`labour.tex`, `health.tex`) which the main file reads via `\externaldocument` (I've also used `\input` but with the same disappointing results).

I want to write in labour something like:

> In Chapter health we find...

How can I reference the name of a file within another file, none of which is the main one?

I've tried the `xr` package, but as far I can tell (not much, admittedly) it helps cross-reference objects such as equations existing in a separate file, but I couldn't figure out how to reference the name of another file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does the solution in [Get the title instead of the number of a referenced chapter/section?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/get-the-title-instead-of-the-number-of-a-referenced-chapter-section) help?

Comment: Why do you want to reference the file name? I understand, they have the same names as the chapters, but wouldn't it be better to reference the chapter titles, with `\label{chapter:health}` and `In Chapter \nameref{chapter:health}`, making them independent of the the filename?

Comment: use `\label` as Christian says, with `\input` then you don't need xr or external document

Answer (score 2):

A possible setup... the reference style has to be changed, from some colours and perhaps to `""` or something like that.

### main.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nameref}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

In Chapter \ref{chapter:health} we see, whereas in Chapter \ref{chapter:labour} it's shown that...

\input{health.tex}


\input{labour.tex}

\end{document}
```

### health.tex

```
\chapter{This is the Health chapter}\label{chapter:health}%
\blindtext
```

### labour.tex

```
\chapter{Labour chapter}\label{chapter:labour}
\blindtext
```

Comment: And if instead of the title, I want to reference their number (as defined by their respective order of inclusion)? For example, "In Chapter 1 we see, whereas in Chapter 2 it's shown that...", where Chapter 1 was the health file included with \input before the labour file, which would therefore be chapter 2

Comment: Chapter~\ref{chapter:health}, etc. Of course!

Comment: @user60648: You did not write, that you want chapter numbers as reference, see your post ;-) See `In Chapter health` ... this is misleading

Comment: Christian, it was an added comment, which did include the word 'instead' at the beginning. I thought it did not merit asking a new question, and was more a follow-up from my original post. Sorry if I've misled anyone!

Comment: @user60648: To which comment do you refer?