# What is the command for writing out the chapter name in the memoir class?

Tags: memoir, chapters

Say I have `\chapter{Test Chapter}` in my document, and I want to insert the title of the chapter into some code or into the text further down the document, what is the command for inserting the previous chaptertitle? I have tried `\thechapter` but it only inserts the number of the chapter.

The command `\thechapter` is also used somewhere in my preamble, so I don't want to redefine that command, lest it'll mess up something else.

As stated, I use the memoir class.

Comment: Duplicate of [Get the title instead of the number of a referenced chapter/section?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6238/5764) or [Get current “section” name without label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75168/5764).

Comment: @Werner, not really because `nameref` is not needed in this case ;-)

Comment: @daleif: Neither is `memoir`. :)

Comment: @Werner, no but the question is explicitly asking about memoir.

Comment: @daleif: The reason I mention this is because [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) works with [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) making the posted duplicate solutions usable, *or* you can use `\titleref` (out-of-the-box built by `memoir`).

Comment: @Werner, well actually, internally `nameref` is mapped to the `memoir` interface when used with `memoir` (as far as I remember)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use references

```
\chapter{Some title}
\label{chap:some}
```

then later

```
\ref{chap:some} -> chapter number
\pageref{chap:some} -> page number for the start of this chapter
\titleref{chap:some} -> the title of the chapter
```

`\titleref` is build into `memoir`