# Reference part of the title of the section

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, nameref

There are good answers already on how to refer to [the title of the section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/get-the-title-instead-of-the-number-of-a-referenced-chapter-section); and [both the title and the number of the section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/nameref-how-to-display-section-name-and-its-number)

What I want to do is use the part of the Title; rather than the whole of the title.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction: this is the first theory}
\label{intro}
In the  \nameref{intro}...
\end{document}
```

I want to get "In the **Introduction**" rather than "In the **Introduction: this is the first theory**".

Comment: Can you provide any rule how TeX/LaTeX etc. should determine which part of the title is interesting? ;-) And you have some typos in your document...

Comment: ok, I have corrected the type. I was thinking if there is a way to directly tell  the Title when assigning  the label for example. \label[Introduction]{intro}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the optional argument of the `\chapter` command should not be used but 'any' another free text, there are some ways, e.g. redefining `\@currentlabelname` to use `\nameref` still.

I provide a way with the powerful `zref` package for a new command named  `\labelshort[optional text]{labelname}` and `\nameshortref` and establishing a new label property `shorttitle` and having some more flexibility.

Use the optional argument of `\nameshortref` to add some more explanatory text or correct grammar.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[user,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@currentshorttitle}{}
\zref@newprop{shorttitle}{\@currentshorttitle}
\zref@addprop{main}{shorttitle}

\NewDocumentCommand{\labelshort}{om}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueT{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\@currentshorttitle}{#1}%
    \zlabel{#2}%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \label{#2}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nameshortref}{O{}m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#2}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#2}{anchor}}{#1\zref@extract{#2}{shorttitle}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction: this is the first theory}
\labelshort[Introduction]{intro}

\section{Foo section}\labelshort[Foo]{foosect}

\clearpage

See \nameshortref[In the ]{intro} or \nameref{intro} or \nameshortref[in the ]{foosect}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for providing a solution that is independent of how the chapter should appear in the table of contents.

Comment: @Tiuri: I had a similar idea to your one in my mind but it was too restrictive concerning the optional title, in my point of view. Your solution is clever anyway!

Comment: is this working?

Comment: @Dellu: Yes, it works

Comment: I am getting "Undefined control sequence \labelshort"

Comment: @Dellu: I just copied again from my post here to my disk and this time, it works!

Answer (score 5):

The `\chapter` macro takes an optional argument that is used instead of the proper title (for printing) in the table of contents and in references. So to have `\nameref{intro}` print just `Introduction`, you just need to supply this short title as the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter[Introduction]{Introduction: this is the first theory}
\label{intro}
In the  \nameref{intro}...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Basically, this answers the question. But, I still need this to work for subsections. Supplying optional text for subsections doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works the same way for all levels (just tested it). If it doesn't work for you, than something else in your code is interfering.

Comment: oh, thanks. Yes, it is working. Just find out that the Table of contents also changes. I was not expecting that. I will try @christian's solution.