# Simultaneously get all forms of name reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, nameref

Is there a possibility of getting (within the same document) the various form of a chapter or section title, similarly to what the `nameref` package does (possibly not conflicting with loading `hyperref`), e.g.:

The following minimal working example lets me get `My moderately long chapter title` and `My moderately long section title`, but I would like to get `My short chapter title` and `My very long, rich and complex chapter title` (and `section` counterparts) in a similar manner.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

% nameref is imported by hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref} % Extensive support for hypertext in LaTeX

\begin{document}

\chapter[My moderately long chapter title]{My very long, rich and complex chapter title}
\chaptermark{My short chapter title}
\label{chapter_title}

Some text.

\section[My moderately long section title]{My very long, rich and complex section title}
\label{section_title}

Some text.
\nameref{chapter_title}, \nameref{section_title}.

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Ideally, it would be something like:

- `\longnameref{chapter_title}` -> `My very long, rich and complex chapter title`
- `\middlenameref{chapter_title}` -> `My moderately long chapter title`
- `\shortnameref{chapter_title}` -> `My short chapter title`

and the respective `section` counterparts.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388510/103046) can be a starting point for you.

Comment: @Tiuri: Good link to two extremely useful answers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modified version of the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388510/103046.

I used the very powerful `zref` package and defined new label properties named `shorttitle`, `marktitle` and `longtitle` which use the short section title, the chapter mark title or the long title after `\refstepcounter` and `\label` is applied.

The `\chaptermark` macro is changed slightly in order to define `\@currentmarktitle` which is expanded and stored with `\zlabel` at its usage.

The macros `\shortnameref`, `\longnameref` and `\middlenameref` check first whether the label is defined and if this is true, add the hyperlink automatically.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[user,hyperref]{zref}

\makeatletter

% Empty dummy macros
\providecommand{\@currentshorttitle}{}
\providecommand{\@currentlongtitle}{}
\providecommand{\@currentmarktitle}{}

\zref@newprop{shorttitle}{\@currentshorttitle}
\zref@newprop{longtitle}{\@currentlongtitle}
\zref@newprop{marktitle}{\@currentmarktitle}
\zref@addprops{main}{shorttitle,longtitle,marktitle}


\NewDocumentCommand{\shortnameref}{m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{shorttitle}}%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\longnameref}{m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{longtitle}}%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\middlenameref}{m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{marktitle}}%
  }%
}


\xpretocmd{\chaptermark}{\def\@currentmarktitle{#1}}{}{}% Let \chaptermark define \@currentmarktitle{}

\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
}{%
  \def\@currentshorttitle{#1}%
  \def\@currentlongtitle{#2}%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
}{\typeout{Success}}{}

\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
}{%
  \def\@currentmarktitle{}%
  \def\@currentshorttitle{#7}%
  \def\@currentlongtitle{#8}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
}{\typeout{Success again}}{}



\usepackage{hyperref} % Extensive support for hypertext in LaTeX

\AtBeginDocument{
\let\latex@@label\label
\RenewDocumentCommand{\label}{m}{%
  \latex@@label{#1}%
  \zlabel{#1}%
}
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\chapter[My moderately long chapter title]{My very long, rich and complex chapter title}
\chaptermark{My short chapter title}
\label{chapter_title}

Some text.

\section[My moderately long section title]{My very long, rich and complex section title}
\label{section_title}

\subsection[My moderately long subsection title]{My very long, rich and complex subsection title} \label{subsection_title}


Some text.

\clearpage
\tiny
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  chapter & \longnameref{chapter_title} & \shortnameref{chapter_title} & \middlenameref{chapter_title}\tabularnewline
  section & \longnameref{section_title} & \shortnameref{section_title} & \tabularnewline
  subsection & \longnameref{subsection_title} & \shortnameref{subsection_title} & \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]